Open a view without waiting for the method to execute in ASP.NET Core
I need the index view to open immediately after calling save_work(), but it doesn't open until the save_work() is completed.
Controller:
public async Task<IActionResult> Save()
{
    save_work();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

Method:
async void save_work()
{
    //save data from DbContext to file
}


your async void save_work() does compile?

you'd probably need to return a Task, but not sure that's going to work unless the method is running as a service?  Seems like the redirect would cancel the method.

I changed code to
Controller:
public IActionResult Save()
{
    Task.Run(() => save_work());
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

Method:
void save_work()
{
    //save data with ADO.NET to file
    //DbContext is not accessible here
}

